# Identifying programming language

Tags: programming-languages, embedded

I've been given a very small snippet of code and it piqued my curiosity. I'm wondering what the language is. I'd like to put the snippet up but it belongs to someone else and they wouldn't appreciate it being posted.

Suffice to say that what I've received looks like a function with a *.sub filename.

- The keyword `macro` is used A LOT with a macro name following the keyword, like a function call with what would appear to be arguments separated by a comma.
- `if` statements are terminated by `endif`.
- The program was written for an embedded device (SiLabs device if I remember correctly).
- Comments are denoted by `;`.
- End of commands are denoted by and end of line.

I've programmed in C/C++/C# and so my broader programming experience is lacking. Does anyone know what language I'm referring to?

Comment: Try short listing from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28syntax%29
as said by nikhita dkslfslg, it must be some assembly language

Comment: Probably code for [Keil's A51 macro assembler](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/).  A macro assembler supports the fundamental machine code instruction level but additionally uses predefined and user defined macros to provide higher level language features in an easier to read and follow form.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess [8051](/questions/tagged/8051), based on the front page of the [SiLabs](http://www.silabs.com/) website.

Should look something like this:

http://www.microapl.co.uk/asm2c/sample8051asm.html

To distinguish it from other assembly languages, you'd look for instructions like `SETB`, `CJNE`, `DJNZ`, and arguments like `@R1`, `DPTR`, `ACC`.  8051 can also address individual bits of some memory locations, written as `ACC.7` or `P0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Assembly language, but syntax may vary. Different assemblers features different syntax, also syntax may vary depending upon hardware used.

For Ex comment syntax -

- '#' are used for  i386, x86-64 etc
- ';' are used AMD 29K family, motorola, PowerPC

Also some high level assemblers hides some abstractions

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an assembly language. Hard to tell for which micro controller/microprocessor it is for though.